# How to draw a shape as an object without using an inherited class

Tags: vb.net, class, inheritance, controls, shapes

I have a class to draw some shapes with mouse evemnts and some properties.
If I use inherited class (inherit control) everiting is OK, otherwise there is nothing to show.
because I set myclass of location and size to use mouse events.
How can I make a shape as an object without using an inherited class.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Shape





Public x1 As Integer
    Public x2 As Integer
    Public y1 As Integer
    Public y2 As Integer
    Public Sub New(x1 As Integer, y1 As Integer, x2 As Integer, y2 As Integer, ByRef g As Graphics)
        MyBase.New()
        Me.x1 = x1 : Me.x2 = x2 : Me.y1 = y1 : Me.y2 = y2
        draw(g)

        Me.Left = x1
        Me.Top = y1
        Me.Width = x2 - x1
        Me.Height = y2 - y1

    End Sub
    Public Sub draw(ByRef egraphics As Graphics)
        Dim _mybrush As Brush ' brush to fill vertex
        _mybrush = New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.White)
        Dim _mypen As New Pen(Color.Black, 5) ' make pen to draw
        _mypen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Solid
        egraphics.FillRectangle(_mybrush, New Rectangle(x1, y1, (x2 - x1), (y2 - y1))) ' dont change between this line and next line if change you can not to see border
        egraphics.DrawRectangle(_mypen, New Rectangle(x1, y1, (x2 - x1), (y2 - y1))) ' dont change between this line and next line if change you can not to see border
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. If you don't want to inherit a class then don't. If you're actually implying that you want a control without inheriting the `Control` class then you're out of luck, because inheriting the `Control` class is what makes a type a control. Maybe you want to do something like the [`LineShape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.lineshape.aspx) from the VB PowerPacks, where multiple shapes are hosted by one control.

Comment: If what you're actually asking is how to draw the class you show the code for above then you would need to handle the `Paint` event of the form or control you want to draw on and pass `e.Graphics` to that `draw` method.  That's just going to draw pixels on the screen though.  There's nothing to raise a `Click` event or that sort of thing. It's hard to tell whether that's what you want because it's not clear what "draw a shape as an object" means.

Comment: By the way, there's no good reason for that `egraphics` parameter to be declared `ByRef` in that `draw` method.  For reference types, which `Graphics` is, you only declare `ByRef` if you're assigning an object to the parameter inside the method.

Comment: Thanks jmcilhinney. I really want to draw a directed(with cap at end or start) bezier line with caption that can control and move it by mouse events like [LineShape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.lineshape.aspx). How can I do it.

Comment: You could define your own class that incorporates the functionality to draw the shape, perform a hit test, etc, and then just handle the events, e.g. Mouse Click, of the control you're drawing on.